# In .Net Core how to rewrite image paths for environment?

Tags: css, image, asp.net-core, url-rewriting, .net-core

I'm new to .Net Core (who isn't it new right?) We want to move all of our images to a image server or CDN. We have set up an image server per environment. So when I'm on DEV I want to hit the Dev Image Server, etc...

So I have LiveContent.liveWebsite.com and DevContent.devWebsite.com. That are separate servers from the liveWebsite.com and devWebsite.com.

I see that I can read in a server variable from configuration and place it in front in razor for anchor tags

```
<a href=@Model.ImageLocation/images/pages/home/img-medical-staff.jpg">
```

That doesn't work so well for our bundled css:

```
background: #FFF url(/images/pages/home/img-medical-staff.jpg);
```

I thought about using an write rule for it, I never done that. I don't know if that will work?

What is the best solutions for making making these image paths configurable per environment?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use SASS or LESS?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you might want to think about adding a token-replacement step in your build/release pipeline.

So before releasing a task would replace

```
background: #FFF url({environment}/images/pages/home/img-medical-staff.jpg);
```

with

```
background: #FFF url(DevContent.devWebsite.com/images/pages/home/img-medical-staff.jpg);
```

This can be done with `gulp-token-replace` for exmple https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-token-replace